# How to change a DropDownList's BackGround colour In FLEX?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, flex4.5

This is what I've done so far.

```
       <!-- fill -->
        <!--- Defines the appearance of drop-down list's background fill. -->
        <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" >
            <s:fill>
            <!---  
                The color of the drop down's background fill.
                The default color is 0xFFFFFF.
            -->
                <s:SolidColor id="bgFill" color="#DB9E36"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
```

If you look closely you'll see that I've changed the default value for the `bgFill` color. However, when I run my application, the background color for the dropdownlist is still the default white.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to change?  The background from the prompt area?  Or the down arrow Button?  Or the actual PopUp? Without seeing the full skin; it's tough to tell what you've actually changed.

Comment: That's the only bit I've changed so far. I would like to change the whole PopUp Background... but this `s:Rect` is within the PopUp, so shouldn't what I've done work?

Comment: That code snippet is from the *default* DropDownListSkin file, the only thing I've changed is that `color` value, nothing else. I'd expected to see a good ole dropDownList, the only difference would be that the popUp backgroundColor is orange rather than the default white......

Comment: I've just noticed that, if you want to change a popUp's width you have to `popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="false"`... perhaps there's something analogous I have to do to be able to change the popUp's background colour??

Comment: Are your itemRenderers transparent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy way to do this is by using the contentBackgroundColor style.  Something like this:

```
<s:DropDownList contentBackgroundColor="0xDB9E36" >
    <s:dataProvider>
        <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        </mx:ArrayCollection>           
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:DropDownList>
```

Some more details..

When creating a custom skin; there is a list of properties called contentFill; defined like this:

```
 static private const contentFill:Array = ["bgFill"];
```

You'll notice the value listed here is the bgFill; the same background whose color you are trying to change..  And it can be retrieved publicly by using the contentItem property:

```
override public function get contentItems():Array {return contentFill};
```

The SparkSkin class [which all MXML Skins extend by default] access this value inside of updateDisplayList.  Every property in the contentItems array has it's background color specificed using the contentBackgroundColor and it's alpha specified using contentBackgroundAlpha.

It is a bit misleading that a value is explicitly defined in the MXML then [potentially] overwritten in ActionScript.